# Why printing -1 for this code, I supposed it to be 1 when bit-field is set to 1?

Tags: c, bit-fields

```
#include<stdio.h>  
int main()  
{  
    struct byte  
    {  
        int one:1;  
    };

    struct byte var = {1};  // statement A
    printf("%d", var.one);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Here, what I suppose is that we've limited the bit-memory of integer variable 'one' to 1 only ie; it can only store 0 and 1 and at 'statement A' we've initialized this variable with '1' which should've been fine as 'one' can still hold a bit in its memory but it's printing -1 on console ! Any help ?

Comment: Consider marking an answer as accepted (by clicking the green check mark) if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is *implementation-defined* whether a bit field defined with type `int` is equivalent to `signed int` or `unsigned int`. (This applies only to bit fields; otherwise `int` is exactly the same as `signed int`.)

If `int one:1;` is signed (as it appears to be in your implementation), then that single bit is the sign bit, and the only possible values are `0` and `-1`. The value `1` that you've used to initialize it, since it's out of range, is implicitly *converted* to `-1`. (Actually the result of the conversion is implementation-defined.)

Change the declaration to:

```
unsigned int one:1;
```

and it can have values `0` and `1`. Bit fields should usually be explicitly unsigned unless you really need them to be signed -- and in that case you should use `signed int` rather than `int`.

Comment: So it's an overflow error? I thought `int`'s range would accommodate a larger value (I should state that I almost nothing about C and just curious about this question)

Comment: `int` does; its range is at least -32767 to +32767. But a 1-bit bit field can only hold one of two values, and if it's signed then those values are `-1` and `0`. (Assuming 2's-complement; otherwise it can only hold `0` and perhaps `-0`.)

Comment: I think what is confusing me is where the conversion from int to bit is occurring.

Comment: @JasonSperske: `struct byte var = {1};`. The `int` value `1` is stored in the 1-bit bit-field object `var.one`. That initialization requires an implicit conversion. (There is no "bit" type, but a bit field acts like it's of a type with a limited range.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson, thank you for the answer, now its making some sense. But one part is still unclear to me ie; if that single bit is being used only to store the sign of the variable then how is it storing the value '1' which I assigned to it and how it got implicitly converted ?

Comment: @RamanVerma: Any time you assign a value of one numeric type to an object of another numeric type, it's implicitly converted. If the target type can't hold the value, the conversion has to change the value. Since a 1-bit signed type can *only* hold the values `-1` and `0`, the conversion yields `-1` (though the language doesn't say it *has* to yield that specific value). Remember than in 2's-complement, signed types have one extra negative value. In 8 bits, that gives you -128 .. +127. In 1 bit, it gives you -1 .. 0.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your help @keith thompson !